# accept() call doesn't initialize sockaddr struct

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have written a short TCP server example in C which continually listens for connections on port 12701, and outputs the value of the peer's sockaddr.sa_family to stdout.  The program calls accept() in an infinite loop, which should fill in a `struct sockaddr` with the details of the connection, including sa_family.

However, this doesn't happen correctly for the first TCP connection; sockaddr.sa_family is always zero.  All subsequent connections provide a correct value of two - only the first one is wrong.  Why does this happen?  I haven't been able to find any reports of similar problems, but I suspect I am initializing something incorrectly or misinterpreting the parameters of accept().

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in saddr =
    {
        .sin_family      = AF_INET,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
        .sin_port        = htons(12701),
    };

    // open socket to accept() tcp connections
    int accept_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(accept_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    listen(accept_fd, SOMAXCONN);

    socklen_t addrlen;
    struct sockaddr * addr;
    for(;;)
    {
        addr = (struct sockaddr *) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        int child_fd = accept(accept_fd, addr, &addrlen);

        // why is this always zero the first time?
        printf("addr->sa_family = %d\n", addr->sa_family);

        close(child_fd);
        free(addr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must initialize `addrlen` before calling `accept`. Also, why dynamically allocate? That might just lead to memory leaks (like you have now).

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) do not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making understaning, debugging and maintenance much more difficult.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   NOTE: always pass the pointer returned from a memory allocation to the function `free()` to avoid memory leaks (and in the current scenario, an eventual system crash)  Suggest calling `free()` immediately after calling `close`

Comment: You are correct about the memory leak; this code was copied from a much larger program where the memory will be freed later.  I have fixed that in the example for future clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the call to `accept()` is not being handled correctly.

in the posted code:

1. the call to `accept()` must be checked for a failure.
2. the call to `malloc()` must be checked for a failure
3. the allocated memory must be free'd
4. the `addrlen` parameter to `accept()` must be properly initialized before each call to `accept()`.

The posted code can only handle one connection at a time.  It would be a good idea to allow for multiple simultaneous connections by
having each connection be routed to a `thread`.  However, generating/destroying threads takes a long time, so suggest having a 'pool' of threads that are initially set to 'unused' and passing each connection to a 'currently unused' thread, after marking that thread as 'in use'  When the thread returns, mark it as 'unused', again.

In the following code, no effort has been made to allow for multiple simultaneous connections.

```
for(;;)
{
    addr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if( !addr )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE from stdlib.h
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    addrlen = sizeof( struct sockaddr );
    int child_fd = accept(accept_fd, addr, &addrlen);

    if( -1 == child_fd )
    { // then an error occurred
        perror( "accept failed" );
    }

    else
    { // else, accept successful
        printf("addr->sa_family = %d\n", addr->sa_family);
        close(child_fd);
    }

    free( addr ); // to avoid memory leak
    addr = NULL;  // for safety
}
```

Comment: note that there is no actual need to be calling `malloc()` and `free()` because only a single instance of the `addr` variable is actually needed.

Answer (score 4):

This assumes `AF_INET` for the connection to be setup.

You want to pass to `accept()` the address of a structure suitable to what you bound the listening socket to, that is a `struct sockaddr_in`.

Also `addrlen` needs to be set to the size of what the address of is passed to `accept()`.

```
  for (;;)
  {
    struct sockaddr_in * addr = malloc(sizeof *addr);
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof *addr;

    if (NULL == addr)
    {
       perror("malloc() failed");
       /* exit(), break, continue, whatever ... */
    }

    int child_fd = accept(accept_fd, (struct sockaddr *) addr, &addrlen);
    if (-1 == child_fd)
    {
       perror("accept() failed");
       free(addr);
       addr = NULL;
       /* exit(), break, continue, whatever ... */
    }

    /* Do stuff. */

    close(child_fd);
    free(addr);
  }
```

Comment: a small problem:  the variable `addrlen` needs to be re-initialized before each call to `accept()` as the call modifies the value

Comment: @user3629249: Indeed! Thank you.

Comment: I think you have a mistake - `(-1 = child_fd)` should have `==`

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is the only one that allocates a `sockaddr_in` instead of a `sockaddr` for each call to `accept()`.  Since the listening socket is `AF_INET`, a `sockaddr_in` must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at for instance this documentation : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

And more specifically the description of the addrlen parameter.
This is an inout parameter and you must initialise it properly.

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must
>   initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
>   to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
>   address.'